# muiTheme` was not specified in `Toolbar`

Tags: reactjs, meteor, material-ui

I am unable to figure out what exactly is needed even though I added the attribute `muitheme` in my component.Also  it would be great if someone can suggest what is best resource for learning the implementation of `material ui` in `meteor-react`

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';  
import NavigationExpandMoreIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/expand-more';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import {Toolbar, ToolbarGroup, ToolbarSeparator, ToolbarTitle} from 'material-ui/Toolbar';

class ToolbarExamplesSimple extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props); 
this.state = {
  value: 3,
};
}

// handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});

render() {
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({

  appBar: {
    height: 50,
  },
});
return (
  <Toolbar muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true}>
      <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} >
        <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="All Broadcasts" />
        <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="All Voice" />
        <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="All Text" />
        <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Complete Voice" />
        <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Complete Text" />
        <MenuItem value={6} primaryText="Active Voice" />
        <MenuItem value={7} primaryText="Active Text" />
      </DropDownMenu>
    </ToolbarGroup>
    <ToolbarGroup>
      <ToolbarTitle text="Options" />
      <FontIcon className="muidocs-icon-custom-sort" />
      <ToolbarSeparator />
      <RaisedButton label="Create Broadcast" primary={true} />
      <IconMenu
        iconButtonElement={
          <IconButton touch={true}>
            <NavigationExpandMoreIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
      >
        <MenuItem primaryText="Download" />
        <MenuItem primaryText="More Info" />
      </IconMenu>
    </ToolbarGroup>
  </Toolbar>
);
```

}
}

**Error:** uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined(…)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it works a bit differently..
The quickest/proper way to provide the theme in your app is with the high order component `MuiThemeProvider`. It should be in the root of your app..

Check this section of the docs with more information
http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage.

Example from the docs:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';
import myMaterialTheme from './myMaterialTheme.js';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';


const muiTheme = getMuiTheme(myMaterialTheme);
const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider  muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```